# Dropdown Content Pure CSS

Tags: css, flexbox

Basically I have 4 divs and I would like when a user hovers the **cover-image** div, show the some content(content-description div) on the left side of the div. I don't want to collapse cover-image div at all. You can think of like that: content-description needs to be hidden behind of cover-image and when a user hovers the cover-image, content description needs to be shown on the left side with small animation. I need a ***pure CSS*** solution.

```
<div class="main">
<div class="main-top">
<div class="content-description">
<div class="cover-image"></div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

CSS which was applied to these divs, and  **cannot be changed flex-box properties.**

```
.main{
  width: 180px;
}

.main-top {
  position: relative;
  height: 150px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: flex-end;
}
```

cover-image just includes a background image.

Comment: As always: what have you tried, where are you stuck? Simply stating the problem is not enough and might get your question closed for being too broad, unclear or otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `:hover` psuedo class of your div.  You can hide the content that you want to display in a `position: absolute` div, and the just display it on `div:hover`.

See my code:

HTML:

```
<div class="content-description">
  <div class="content-d-hover">
    <p>
      yay content
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.content-description{
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  position: relative;
}

.content-description:hover .content-d-hover{
  opacity: 1;
  transition: 0.5s all;
}

.content-d-hover{
  position: absolute;
  width: 80px;
  height: 80px;
  top: 10px;
  right: -90px;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: 0.5s all;
}
```

You can also look at [my plunkr](https://next.plnkr.co/edit/rjzISDWnYOKfiYQS?open=lib%2Fscript.js&preview)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Your solution partially works. I have just one more question. If I have a couple of items side by side and I still would like to do same thing. So when the content appears, if there is a item on the left side of the content, the item should be floated left.

Comment: All you have to do is create the hidden element exactly where you want it displayed. When you then hover over the item, the div whil appear where you positioned it. Because you add tje position:absolute to your hidden div, elements can be on top op each other with the z-index.  Unfortunately you cannot float an absolute div, bit you can position it with ‘left:’, ‘right:’, ‘top:’, and ‘bottom:’.